# Which modal verb is correct to use in this sentence? "It is very cloudy, I think it ___ rain."

Tags: modal-verbs

I have an English exercise which says:

> It is very cloudy, I think it ______ rain.

Options:

- might
- must
- can
- can't

I don't know which option is correct and I want a short explanation. I think 'can' is the correct option, but it can be 'might' too, I don't think that 'must' is the correct one at all.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Every sentences has a difference meaning expect **must**.

Here are the rules:

> It can rain

This expresses what the speaker believes is a general truth or known fact, or a strong possibility.

> It could/may rain

This does not express a general truth. The speaker is only expressing a weak possibility.

> It must rain

This is so strange and incorrect, You can't oblige the sky to rain.

> It might rain

It expresses a weaker probability, there is more reserve or doubt on the part of the speaker

In this case, I think **It might rain** and **It may rain** are the best way and most polite.

**can** is generally used to skills, ability and things safe (e.g. He shot to me, I can to die).

Comment: @MADY - It's usually a good idea to wait a little while rather than immediately accepting the first answer!  In this case, I think "It **can** rain" is very awkward and not idiomatic-sounding.  *Can* just expresses ability.  Of course it *can* rain - it always "can" rain.  But only "it *might* rain" expresses a possibility related to the clouds.

Comment: I got it! Another answer could  be "may" and "could", right?

Comment: Why -1? I think my answer is correct.

Comment: @MADY You can use may and could, Them are both correct.

Comment: It's as stangdon said. This answer is not correct. (I didn't downvote though, but I hope you'll consider improving the answer or doing something about it.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I improved it.4

Comment: None of these usages are "polite" or "impolite." It's impossible to be either one when talking about the rain. Also, we would _never_ say "He shot to me" or "I can to die." @Mattew , please learn more about when to use the bare infinitive (hint: some verbs _require_ it.) Also, "can is generally used to skills" is hard to understand. Did you leave out a verb, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

From a comment by [P.E. Dant](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/37009/p-e-dant):

The answer to your exercise question is "might." [**Here**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/might?s=t) is a dictionary definition of this modal (or *auxiliary*) verb. It is used here to express *possibility*. None of the other choices make any sense. "Must" makes no sense, since "must" expresses obligation, and although farmers wish they *could,* no-one can force the clouds to rain. "Can't" makes no sense for the same reason that "can" makes no sense.